# How do you use Fritztrainer DVD with Fritz 15?

Tags: software

I recently just got The Modern Grand Prix Attack Fritztrainer DVD, and I only have Fritz 15. I put in the activation code and can see the video, but the problem is that the chess board next to the video doesn't move. Hence, I can't see the pieces move when the IM goes over the games and variations. When I remove the DVD and put in the Fritz 15 disc, Fritz 15 works, but the Fritztrainer isn't there anymore. I couldn't find any customer service phone number. How do I get the Fritztrainer to work?

Answer (score 2):

The [Chessbase support site describes the process](http://help.chessbase.com/Fritz/15/Eng/index.html?chess_media_system.htm) of viewing chess media files (or, what many call Fritz Trainer videos) as follows:

> If you have the lecture on a CD or DVD, [...] then
>   you simply open a file using "File – Open – Chess Media File". The
>   program will open a chess media window and you can sit back and watch
>   the game.

Here is a screencap of my doing this process for the Fritz Trainer, Fit for the French by GM Viktor Bologan:

[image: Fritz 15 opening a Fritz Trainer on my hard drive]

Note that very often the first video in a Fritz Trainer will be just the GM talking and giving you an overview. Then, you won't see any pieces moving (e.g., GM Garry Kasparov on the Queen's Gambit rapidly discusses lines without showing them on the board).

Finally, if you're opening the video files using these instructions and they don't show pieces moving when they're supposed to, you may have gotten your files from a disreputable source that has stripped them of their proprietary Chessbase metadata. In that case, you'll want to try to get a refund or download the Fritz Trainer from Chessbase.